# Is there any way to dump/view the jni globalref pool?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am doing a lot of JNI work recently and would like to monitor (or at least dump) the contents of the jni globalref pool. Google hasn't provided anything helpful yet.

I noticed that if you do trigger a globalref-pool exhaustion it does list the top 10 items in the pool so I am hopeful there is some way of getting at this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Dalvik VM, the global and (for the current thread) local ref tables are printed to the log by `dvmDumpJniReferenceTables()` in [dalvik/vm/Jni.cpp.](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-release/vm/Jni.cpp)  This is called from `Dalvik_dalvik_system_VMDebug_dumpReferenceTables()` in [dalvik/vm/native/dalvik_system_VMDebug.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-release/vm/native/dalvik_system_VMDebug.cpp), which is accessible from Java source code via the `dalvik.system.VMDebug.dumpReferenceTables()` [method](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/kitkat-release/dalvik/src/main/java/dalvik/system/VMDebug.java).

The approved way to call it is through the `android.os.Debug.dumpReferenceTables()` [method](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/kitkat-release/core/java/android/os/Debug.java), which is marked `@hide`, i.e. it's not part of the public API.  So you should call it via reflection.

I don't know what if anything this does under ART.